# Kentico 9: upcoming events widget not showing any content

Tags: kentico

I'm having trouble getting event details to "Upcoming Events" widget in Kentico 9. Problem is there's no "Path" attribute to set in the widget configuration window.

[image]
*above: upcoming events configuration window*

Can somebody help me with this please.

However "Event calendar" widget shows all the event without any issue after setting Events' path correctly.
[image]
*above: Event calendar configuration window*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **Widgets** application, select your widget, go to *Properties* tab, select your *Path* property and check *Display field in the editing form* checkbox and save your changes.

[image]

Comment: Fixed. Thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

If you go this widget and go to it's path property, you will notice that it uses a macro to set default path like this

```
   {%cmscontext.currentdepartment.nodealiaspath#%}/Calendar/%
```

So by default the location will evaluated from here unless you go here and change the path for this widget for your use.

You can also enable this field **"Display field in the editing form"**. This will start showing the path field in the widget properties.

I think this will resolve your problem.

Attaching a screen shot for you.

[image]

Cheers,
Chetan

Comment: Fixed. Thank you :D

Comment: Kindly mark it as a correct answer if it has helped you. This will help others too in the future.